# Pyspark handling array of struct type in automated way

Tags: python, arrays, apache-spark, struct, pyspark

I am having an json with struct and "array of struct datatype", I am able to parse the json in automated way for struct type. For array of struct type, I need to handle the array of struct, for which my code is not working. I have the approach I am not sure where to fit in the code. Ending up with an error

Below is my json

```
{
"Details": {
    "ReferenceDetails": "6CK",
    "Number": "77",
    "Reason": 1,
    "port1": "Nav",
    "port2": "Sri",
    "Disrupted": "2008-02-08T00:00:00Z"
},
"CD": {
    "FirstName": "Sam",
    "LastName": "HE",
    "Country": "IN",
    "County": "Indi",
    "Postcode": "12",
    "Address1": "India",
    "Address2": "",
    "Town": "Indi",
    "EMail": "aro@in.com",
    "TelephoneCountryCode": "+1",
    "TelephoneRgn": "965895",
    "Telephone": "65895",
    "Agent": "",
    "IsAgent": true,
    "IdB": true,
    "IsYes": true
},
"Passengers": [{
    "FirstName": "D",
    "LastName": "Sunil"
}],
"IpAddress": "123223",
"Type": "IND",
"Language": "en",
"IsValidated": true,
"CF": "01",
"TimeStamp": "2018-12-18 05:19:45.998",
"Code": "INS"
}
```

I have tried to change the datatype using regex by changing arrat< to nothing and end of ">>" to ">" . Reason for doing this is I have the code, that differentiates struct type. Now I wanted to make array of struct to be of struct

Control over the datatypes is taken by df.dtypes looping over this dtypes. Below section has the code

Below approach was tried:
For array of struct type I am using explode option and it is working fine. But I wanted without explode option, as explode is handling by taking control over column name

Below is the snippet for array of struct handling with explode

```
flat_df = flat_df.withColumn("Passenger_FirstName", explode(flat_df.Passengers.FirstName)).withColumn("Passenger_LastName", explode(flat_df.Passengers.LastName)).drop("Passengers")
```

Below is the code to read the json and flatten out which I have tried for array of struct in automated fashing by replacing the "array<" with "" and ">>" with 
">". Solution for this would be very very helpful

```
read_json=spark.read.option("charset", "UTF-8").option("multiline", "false").json(sc.wholeTextFiles("s3a://folder1/folder2/",minPartitions=32).values())

flat_cols = [c[0] for c in read_json.dtypes if c[1][:6] != 'struct']
nested_cols = [c[0] for c in nested_df.dtypes if c[1][:6] == 'struct']
flat_df = read_json.select(flat_cols + [col(nc+'.'+c).alias(nc+'_'+c) for nc in nested_cols for c in read_json.select(nc+'.*').columns])

for c in read_json.dtypes:
     re.sub('array<','',read_json.dtypes)
     re.sub('>>','>',read_json.dtypes)
```

Error I have faced is below:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 2, in 
>     File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/Anaconda-5.0.1/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 155, in sub
>       return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
>   TypeError: expected string or buffer

I expect all my nested columns has to be flattened out in single dataframe . I do not want to touch the attribute names

Comment: I work with `PySpark`, but hardly used `json` format. Sorry man!

Comment: Ok you can copy that json in an file read it in pyspark and copy the code as it is . If it is in dataframe it will be in our control well. Only bottleneck for me is , from the read dataframe  I have to replace string "array<" with "" and ">>" with ">" . Where I am stuck is I am looping with  read_json.dtypes I am facing some issue.

Comment: Can you copy the `dataframe` resulting from `JSON` to your question, then I can investigate ?